# Setting enum properties across multiple interdependent enum properties in a script

Tags: python, modifiers, properties

The Data Transfer modifier offers multiple enum properties which in the interface can be changed with clicking (exclusively sets one value and disables the others) or shift-clicking/dragging (allows to set multiple values).

[image: Data Transfer Modifier Example 1]

This behaviour not only affects each of these enum properties on their own, but also reaches across all the other properties, unsetting previously set values in property A if values in set B are set. (To illustrate this, the next image shows the state of the modifier from the previous image after clicking on "UVs" - the values "Sharp" and "UV Seam" are unset in the other enum property)

[image]

In the interface, setting multiple values in multiple enum properties is possible through shift-clicking across them, but when scripting the same behaviour I run into a problem:

```
obj.modifiers["DataTransfer"].data_types_loops_uv = {"UV"}
```

... does what one expects, and so does - **mind the different property being set here** (!) ...

```
obj.modifiers["DataTransfer"].data_types_edges = {"SHARP_EDGE"}
```

... but the second line also removes the previously set "UV" value **on the previous property** (!) ...

Lacking shift-click in a script :) and not knowing of a way to set both `data_types_loops_uv` and `data_types_edges` in one assignment (and rather wanting to avoid working with multiple DataTransfer modifiers for each property) I am now stuck and would appreciate any help!

Comment: The term 'radio' is generally not used and instead 'enum' is used for this type of UI element. It may be better to replace the word 'radio' with 'enum' in your question.

Comment: Thanks @RayMairlot, I was in fact unsure how to call it and went for interface design lingo :) sounds more like a blender question now that i edited everything!

Comment: Given the discrepancy between setting the enums with code and UI, this could be bugreportworthy, which if anything will clarify the situation.

Comment: I'll maybe wait some more (maybe someone who has touched the internals of this will add something), but in any case this is a valuable hint, thanks - I'll go with it if nothing else turns up. (and maybe I'll discuss it with one of the core devs either way :))

Comment: I just opened a bug report for this: https://developer.blender.org/T46522

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Confirmed as a bug here https://developer.blender.org/T46522, Bastien Montagne is already on it with full dedication. Amazing :)

Case closed.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is [`data_types_edges`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_76_release/bpy.types.DataTransferModifier.html#bpy.types.DataTransferModifier.data_types_edges) as well as the other data transfer attributes are python [`set`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set) objects and you are overwriting the entire set losing the previous values.

To add an element to a set, us the [`|=`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#set.update) operator.

```
import bpy

data_transfer = bpy.context.object.modifiers["DataTransfer"]

data_transfer.data_types_edges |= {'SHARP_EDGE'}
```

It seems that the `add()` and `update()` function do not affect the modifier; so just use `|=` instead.

Comment: The hassle is that running your code above will add ok to the data_type_edges enum selection, but will clear any selections in the other types, (verts, loops, polys).  eg append data_transfer.data_types_verts_vgroup |= {'VGROUP_WEIGHTS'} to your script

Comment: There was another answer like this already (which was deleted by the author) ... like batFINGER already says (and like it says in the title of the question), this is not about modifying a single property, but multiple ones, that somehow, unexpectedly alter each other under the hood. I did yet another edit to my question now to point this out even more clearly. :)